# Woocommerce filter 'woocommerce_cart_total_discount' does not fire up

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

Apologies in advance as I have just picked up WooCommerce.

Earlier I was writing my whole logic in the action *'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals'* like below:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', array($this,'calculate_total_price_of_cart'), 10, 1);

function calculate_total_price_of_cart($p_cart_obj){
  $p_cart = $p_cart_obj->get_cart();

  //code to extract info and add into the cart


   $discount_total = fetch_discount_amount($p_cart); //calls helper function and get amount to be discounted

   //code to update the cart for discount
   $p_cart->discount_total = $discount_total;//this doesn't work

}
```

The above doesn't work.

The other solution I thought to change the discounted price by using the filter 'woocommerce_cart_total_discount' like following, but its not working either:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_total_discount', array($this,'apply_custom_discount'));
function mitte_woocommerce_cart_total_discount($total_discount, $instance)
{
    //some code
    return $custom_discount;
}
```

Again, thanks for helping out as I am stuck and couldn't find any resource to fix this.

Comment: Are you using this code in a plugin? where is the code for `get_elgible_sku_for_discount()`… Remember that: *"Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."***

Comment: Yes, using this code in plugin. 'get_elgible_sku_for_discount' is some function written in the plugin which just returns the eligible SKUs which needs to be made free(by considering every case I mentioned in the question). Regarding excessive description: I wanted to explain it in detail. Let me edit the question.

Comment: The property `discount_total` doesn't exist for [`WC_Cart`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#$discount_cart) so this can not work. You should better try existing `discount_cart` and `discount_cart_tax` properties instead.